# Debian Auto Login Activation Caused Black Screen During Boot On VMWare WorkStation

Tags: linux, boot, debian, vmware-workstation

I have Debian  latest version on my vmware workstation.
Default user was different from root.
I tried to activate auto login as root user and now i stuck on a black screen during boot.
Here is the commends & what i did :

**Auto login – GNOME gmd3**

> Like I said it’s a simple change. Just open and edit the file called
> /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf, assuming you’re using GNOME Display
> Manager(gmd3) a your main Display Manager. You might want to try out
> other desktops as well. Here’s a link to Add/Remove different desktop
> Managers in Linux.

```
root@ramtin:~# leafpad /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
```

In the daemon section un-comment the 2 lines for automatic login. It should finally look like this

```
[daemon]
# Enabling automatic login
  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
  AutomaticLogin = root
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Kali V2023.2 running on VMware Workstation V17.

Root in Kali is like other Linux and Windows in that it is generally not set up.

Your initial user is the correct admin user and runs a command either as is or with sudo and your password.

Try logging on with your regular user.

FWIW, I use XFCE for Kali as it works better in a Kali environment than Gnome.

Whichever - root is hidden and generally do not use.

If your regular user does not work, you may need to reinstall Kali and get data from your backups.

I keep backups of virtual machines on another machine to recover if something goes wrong.

Comment: It does n't show login page after restart. So i can not enter any thing. screen is black.

Comment: You log in with your own user? and the screen is black?   Something is very wrong with your Kali installation.

Comment: The VM is just a machine.  Try restarting and see if you can log in with your regular userid after restarting.

Comment: *Kali is healthy* It clearly isn't otherwise you wouldn't be here asking. Fortunately VMs are much easier to recover than actual installation provided users have backups as mentioned in this answer (you have backups, don't you?). In the absence of backups then it usually takes a LOT less time reinstalling than trying to recover from mistakes. If you end up doing that then make sure: 1) NEVER login as `root` and 2) avoid automatic login in any case (there's a reason why even Windows remove this option as the default (and made it even harder than Linux to explicitly enable)).